# Подскажите, что за ошибка:

Tags: php

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'komar155'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за ошибка и как ее убрать?

Comment: Проверь логин/пароль. Если всё верно, то выложи сюда строку кода, на котором ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Походу не удалось установить соединение с базой данных

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в пароле, но возможно в правах на действие.

Comment: возможно в пользователе, потому как хостеры дописывают префиксы/постфиксы к имени и названию баз

Answer (score 0):

перепроверь пароль логин и правильность написания адреса к серверу мускул. Если там все правильно пиши в ТП своего хостинга.